# Horizontal tabs scroll in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, tabs

I have the below code. The number of article-type-items is dynamic. There can be more than 15 types at a time. I want to make this scrollable horizontally with a left and right arrow at the ends if it exceeds the width. This should be responsive across all devices including Desktop, Laptops, tablets and mobiles. Arrows should be visible only if the width is exceeded. How can I achieve this in HTML/CSS?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

````
<div class="container">
      <!-- Tabs here -->
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="me-3 article-type-item">
          <p>Searched Result</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-3 article-type-item">
          <p>Trending Topics</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-3 article-type-item">
          <p>Reporting</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-3 article-type-item">
          <p>Accounting</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible only with .css

We can use rxjs fromEvent operator to "listen" the window.resize.

So imagine a .html like

```
  <div class="wrapper" *ngIf="{scrolled:obs$|async} as data">
    <div #tabgroup class="tabgroup">
      <div class="tab" [class.tab-last]="last && !data.scrolled"
                *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3,4];let last=last">{{i}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows" [style.display]="data.scrolled" >
      <button (click)="scroll(-60)"><</button
      ><button (click)="scroll(60)">></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

We can to have, see that we create the obs$ in AfterViewInit

```
  @ViewChild('tabgroup') tabgroup!: ElementRef;
  obs$!:Observable<any>

  ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.obs$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((x) =>
          this.tabgroup &&
          this.tabgroup.nativeElement.offsetWidth <=
          this.tabgroup.nativeElement.scrollWidth
          ? null
          : 'none'
        )
     );
   }
  scroll(value: number) {
    this.tabgroup.nativeElement.scrollBy(value, 0);
  }
```

A .css like

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;

  }
  .tabgroup {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .tab {
    min-width: 60px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid silver;
  }
  .arrows {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
  }
  .tab-last{
    margin-right:42px;
  }
```

resolve the question.

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2j92un?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: If your tabs are dynamic, instead use ngAfterViewInit, create the obs$ after create the tabs